# Aliasing when using JAI

Tags: java, antialiasing, jai

Dear Stackoverflow community,

so currently i am using the Java Advanced Imaging API to realize a pane where you have a picture whose corners you can freely move around and scale the whole thing as you please. I took care, that the resulting picture won't be much bigger or smaller than the original thing. Now some people using our software complained, that the resulting image has some aliasing in it. I tried some anti-aliasing measures (as low-pass filtering the whole result, set better interpolators and graphic rendering hints) but i can't seem to get rid of the problem. Anyone any ideas?

My code:

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    ParameterBlock params = new ParameterBlock();
    params.addSource(previewImage); // source is the input image
    int w = previewImage.getWidth(); // Set to the original width of the
                                     // image
    int h = previewImage.getHeight(); // Set to the original height of image

    Point tl = new Point((int) cornersTrans[0].getX(), (int) cornersTrans[0].getY()); // The
                                                                                        // new
                                                                                        // top
                                                                                        // left
                                                                                        // corner
    Point tr = new Point((int) cornersTrans[1].getX(), (int) cornersTrans[1].getY()); // The
                                                                                        // new
                                                                                        // top
                                                                                        // right
                                                                                        // corner
    Point bl = new Point((int) cornersTrans[2].getX(), (int) cornersTrans[2].getY()); // The
                                                                                        // new
                                                                                        // bottom
                                                                                        // left
                                                                                        // corner
    Point br = new Point((int) cornersTrans[3].getX(), (int) cornersTrans[3].getY()); // The
                                                                                        // new
                                                                                        // bottom
                                                                                        // right
                                                                                        // corner
    try {
        params.add(new WarpPerspective(PerspectiveTransform.getQuadToQuad(0, 0, 0, h, w, h, w, 0, tl.x, tl.y, bl.x, bl.y, br.x, br.y, tr.x, tr.y).createInverse()));
    } catch (NoninvertibleTransformException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (!isInMovement)
        params.add(Interpolation.getInstance(Interpolation.INTERP_BICUBIC));

    PlanarImage image = smoothConvolve( JAI.create("warp", params) );

    int y0 = (int) (cornersTrans[0].getY() < cornersTrans[1].getY() ? cornersTrans[0].getY() : cornersTrans[1].getY());
    int x0 = (int) (cornersTrans[0].getX() < cornersTrans[2].getX() ? cornersTrans[0].getX() : cornersTrans[2].getX());
    int x1 = (int) (cornersTrans[3].getX() > cornersTrans[1].getX() ? cornersTrans[3].getX() : cornersTrans[1].getX());
    int y1 = (int) (cornersTrans[3].getY() > cornersTrans[2].getY() ? cornersTrans[3].getY() : cornersTrans[2].getY());

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
 //     g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,0.5f));
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,    RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_ALPHA_INTERPOLATION_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_COLOR_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_COLOR_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.drawImage((Image) image.getAsBufferedImage(), x0, y0, x1, y1, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null);

    if (enableEditing) {
        int width = (int) (cornersTrans[3].getX() - cornersTrans[0].getX());
        int height = (int) (cornersTrans[3].getY() - cornersTrans[0].getY());

        g.drawImage(moveIcon, (int) cornersTrans[0].getX() + (width / 2) - (MOVE_ICON_WIDTH / 2), (int) (cornersTrans[0].getY() + (height / 2) - (MOVE_ICON_WIDTH / 2)),
                (int) (cornersTrans[0].getX() + (width / 2) + (MOVE_ICON_WIDTH / 2)), (int) (cornersTrans[0].getY() + (height / 2) + (MOVE_ICON_WIDTH / 2)), 0, 0, moveIcon.getWidth(),
                moveIcon.getHeight(), null);

        if (mode == MODE_DISTORT) {
            for (IntPoint p : cornersTrans)
                drawCircle(g, new Point(p.x, p.y));
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                drawScalingIcon(g2d, i);
        }
    }
}

private PlanarImage smoothConvolve(PlanarImage input){
     int kernelSize = 2;
        // Create an array with enough positions for the kernel.
        float[] kernelMatrix = new float[kernelSize*kernelSize];
        // Fill the array with the data for the kernel. The sum of all array
        // positions will be 1.0.
        for(int k=0;k<kernelMatrix.length;k++)
          kernelMatrix[k] = 1.0f/(kernelSize*kernelSize);
        // Create the kernel using the array.
        KernelJAI kernel = new KernelJAI(kernelSize,kernelSize,kernelMatrix);
        // Run the convolve operator, creating the output image.
        return JAI.create("convolve", input, kernel);       
}
```

I attached an example of how the resulting image looks in a canvas  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6tqX.png). Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I think this is a limitation in the Java2D API. The edges will always be jagged (aliased) when using `drawImage`. However, I once implemented this using a `Shape` (`g.fillXxx()`) and a `TexturePaint` fill (based on a blog article I can't seem to find), and it worked. No time to write a full answer, but give it a try! :-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I would love to know exactly how you solved the problem. I tried what you suggested and did a fill(GeneralPath) with the texture as paint. Well although i feel like it has gotten a bit better, the problem is still there.

What i did:
* Create a GeneralPath with the four corners
* Create a BufferedImage through JAI.create("warp", params), then image.getAsBufferedImage().
* Set some rendering hitn
* g2d.fill(GeneralPath)